# Smoothness of a function after integration w.r.t. one variable

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives, smooth-functions

Let $f:[0,1]\times [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Suppose that for any $t_0\in[0,1]$, $s\mapsto f(t_0,s)$ is a smooth function of $s\in[0,1]$, and that for any $s_0\in[0,1]$, $t\mapsto f(t,s_0)$ is a smooth function of $t\in[0,1]$.

Define $F:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ by $F(t)=\int_0^1f(t,s)ds$. In general, $F$ seems not to be a smooth function of $t$. What might be a good condition on $f$, as weak as possible, to make $F$ smooth in $t$?

Comment: Why do you say that $F$ is not smooth?

Comment: @copper.hat  For example let’s replace $[0,1]$ by $[-1,1]$, and consider $f(x,y)=xy^2/(x^2+y^2)$. $f$ is smooth in $x$ and $y$ separately. Now $F(x)=\int_{-1}^1f(x,y)dy$ satisfies $F(x)=2x-2x^2\cdot \arctan(1/x)$ for $x\neq 0$, and $F(0)=0$. It turns out that the second derivative of $F$ is not continuous at $0$. (The function $f(x,y)$ is an example of a function on the plane whose restriction to every line passing through the origin is continuous but is discontinuous as a function of two variables.)